# Can't scrape the emojis from the html

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, save

[This is the screenshot of html]
I am scraping the profiles(about me ) of twitter accounts . I get the text but unable to scrape the emojis attached , This is the part of my code .

```
    i=1
    while True:
        try:
            x=driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(x).perform()
            print(x.text)
        except:None
        i+=1
```

Comment: The reason is the emojis are stored as images in this instance and not text, so when you print x.text, it'll only display the text inside the selector, not the images.

Comment: Got it , but how can I get them . eg. a profile has this :  ‍Analyst‍‍⚕️ Bacon ninja‍⚕️️ Creator️ Tv fan Gamer.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the Emojis via their alt tags I believe. If x in this case is the element containing the emoji, you can do x.get_attribute('alt').

```
i=1
while True:
    try:
        x=driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(x).perform()
        print(x.get_attribute('alt'))
    except:
        None
    i+=1
```

Comment: <div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-1h8ys4a r-1jeg54m r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Peace </span><img alt="✌" draggable="false" src="https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/270c.svg" class="r-4qtqp9 r-dflpy8 r-sjv1od r-zw8f10 r-10akycc r-h9hxbl"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"> equality </span><img alt="☺" draggable="false" src="https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/263a.svg" class="r-4qtqp9 r-dflpy8 r-sjv1od r-zw8f10 r-10akycc r-h9hxbl"></div>

Comment: The html looks like this , if I get the text i miss the emogis and vice versa .

Comment: you can just print both, after the alt print(x.text)

Comment: It's hard to see without the html, but if what you pasted above is x in the code, you can setup an empty list find all elements within that div, check if it's an img, if it is append the alt tag, if not append the .text of the element to the list, then you can join the list at the end to give you the text and emojis for that div